# Subquery in joomla php mysql

Tags: php, join, joomla, subquery

Ok I realy cant get this working the way I need.
I have 2 tables:

`gerencia_clientes` and `gerencia_vendas`

The first saves my customers and the second saves the invoices

I need to list them using a query like this

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$query = "select * from jos_gerencia_vendas where id_edicao = ".$iddaedicao." order by id_cliente";

$db->setQuery($query);
$list = $db->loadObjectList();
foreach ($list as $item)
```

but instead of ordering by id_cliente, I need the correct syntax to order using the customers that are in another table alphabetically,

example

```
$query = "select * from jos_gerencia_vendas where id_edicao = ".$iddaedicao." order by (select nomecliente from jos_gerencia_clientes)";
```

any help?

Comment: A schema for the table you're trying to use would be really helpful :)

Comment: I think its good practice to change jos_ to #__. Like: SELECT * FROM #__gerencia_vendas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query = "select * from jos_gerencia_vendas AS a 
          LEFT JOIN jos_gerencia_clientes AS b ON b.id_cliente=a.id_cliente
          where a.id_edicao = ".$iddaedicao." 
          order by b.nome_cliente ASC"
```

Comment: now i have another problem, looks like the values i need to select in a foreach loop is not working properly,

Answer (score 1):

There is also a way to execute queries which contain subqueries using the Joomla Platform API.
The basic idea on how to use subqueries is based on [gunjanpatel](https://gist.github.com/gunjanpatel/8663333).

This answer was also posted on [Stackexchange for Joomla](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/1/method-for-creating-a-subquery-using-jdatabase/12404#12404).

Here is an example for executing queries on [Nested Set Models](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/):

SQL query:

```
-- Find the Immediate Subordinates of a Node
SELECT node.title, (COUNT(parent.id) - (sub_tree.depth + 1)) AS depth
FROM lubd3_usergroups AS node,
        lubd3_usergroups AS parent,
        lubd3_usergroups AS sub_parent,
        (
                SELECT node.id, (COUNT(parent.id) - 1) AS depth
                FROM lubd3_usergroups AS node,
                        lubd3_usergroups AS parent
                WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
                        AND node.id = 1
                GROUP BY node.id
                ORDER BY node.lft
        )AS sub_tree
WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
        AND node.lft BETWEEN sub_parent.lft AND sub_parent.rgt
        AND sub_parent.id = sub_tree.id
GROUP BY node.id
-- not showing the parent node
HAVING depth = 1
-- showing the parent node
-- HAVING depth <= 1
ORDER BY node.lft;
```

and the transformed query to be executed by Joomla:

```
// Create the subQuery select statement.
// Nested Set Queries: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/
// CROSS JOIN: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=30875&seqNum=5
$subQuery->select(array('node.id', '(COUNT(parent.id) - 1) AS depth'))
    ->from($db->quoteName('#__usergroups') . 'node')
    ->join('CROSS', $db->quoteName('#__usergroups', 'parent'))
    ->where($db->quoteName('node.lft') . ' BETWEEN  ' . $db->quoteName('parent.lft') . ' AND ' . $db->quoteName('parent.rgt') . ' AND ' . $db->quoteName('node.id') . ' = ' . $db->quote('1'))
    ->group($db->quoteName('node.id'))
    ->order($db->quoteName('node.lft'));

// Create the base select statement.
$query->select(array('node.title', '(COUNT(parent.id) - (sub_tree.depth + 1)) AS depth'))
    ->from($db->quoteName('#__usergroups') . 'node')
    ->join('CROSS', $db->quoteName('#__usergroups', 'parent'))
    ->join('CROSS', $db->quoteName('#__usergroups', 'sub_parent'))
    ->join('CROSS', '(' . $subQuery .') AS sub_tree')
    ->where($db->quoteName('node.lft') . ' BETWEEN  ' . $db->quoteName('parent.lft') . ' AND ' . $db->quoteName('parent.rgt')
    . ' AND ' . $db->quoteName('node.lft') . ' BETWEEN  ' . $db->quoteName('sub_parent.lft') . ' AND ' . $db->quoteName('sub_parent.rgt')
    . ' AND ' . $db->quoteName('sub_parent.id') . ' = ' . $db->quoteName('sub_tree.id'))
    ->group($db->quoteName('node.id'))
    ->having($db->quoteName('depth') . ' = ' . $db->quote('1'))
    ->order($db->quoteName('node.lft'));

// Set the query and load the result.
$db->setQuery($query);
$rowList = $db->loadAssocList();

echo "<pre>";
print_r($rowList);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure on the columns you are using for the database table but this might work:

```
$query = "select * from jos_gerencia_vendas where id_edicao = ".$iddaedicao." order by names ASC";
```

change "names" according to whatever you table column is.

Hope this helps